# Recovering the WinForm design after creating a copy of a form inside of VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

A form contains the main design and has all the code in the code file of that form. I just copied that form and pasted it in same directory in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer where the original form was present. It now shows errors related to resources. As I move forward, it show error:

> error MSB3105: The item "obj\x86\Debug\BAS.frmGI1.resources" was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.

Now I just lost the design of main form. How I can recover the design of the original form?

Comment: It opens Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets file and shows error on different lines too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've *made a copy* of the original form, everything (classes, designer code, etc.) was copied exactly the same. As with any other class, if you have two classes defined with the **exact** same name; they will conflict. Similarly, if you have two files of a *partial* class, and in both files you declare a variable with the **same** name; it will conflict.

---

What you've done is caused the above conflict to occur with the designer...and no need to panic (or resort to version control or whatnot - no pun intended to [criticalfix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16177098/238722)).

Next, let's fix those class names!

1. Simply right-click the duplicate, and [*Exclude from Project*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNxAV.png);
2. Browse to your [project's directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjQ1t.png);
3. Open **`FormName.Designer.vb`** (or **`FormName.Designer.cs`** for C#) with your favorite text editor (**but not**(!) with Visual Studio);
4. Find your form's class (**`MySuperAwesomeForm`** in this example):

   ```
   Partial Class MySuperAwesomeForm
   ```

   In C#:

   ```
   partial class MySuperAwesomeForm // FormName.Designer.cs

   public partial class MySuperAwesomeForm : Form // FormName.cs
   ```
5. Replace all instances of **`MySuperAwesomeForm`** with some other name; example: **`MySuperAwesomeFormTwo`**;
6. Now open **`FormName.vb`** (or **`FormName.cs`** for C#) with your favorite text editor (again, make sure it's **not**(!) Visual Studio);
7. Replace all instances of **`MySuperAwesomeForm`** with the same value used in step # 4; example: **`MySuperAwesomeFormTwo`**;

   - Save and close both files, if they are still open.

Technically, you should only need to replace **`MySuperAwesomeForm`** with **`MySuperAwesomeFormTwo`** on one of the first few lines of each file (where the line starts with **`Public Class`**, **`partial class`**, or **`public partial class`**).

Finally, go back into Visual Studio, and [add the newly re-*classed* form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wNzD.png) back to the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of a form, but you have to change its name (both the file name and the object name) so it won't be confused with the original.  Then, from Visual Studio, you would Add Form ... Existing ... and then select the new form.

Your error message mentions the obj directory, so the error presumably occurred during the build.  I would look at the resources for your project to see what may have been duplicated, if it is something beyond the original file you copied.

If you have lost your original source code, you may not be able to recover it.  I hope you are using some form of source control (VSS, TFS, etc), or at least are making frequent copies to a backed-up network disk?